# 30 Minute Post Delay Not Working With Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delay, nsuserdefaults

How do I create my program that will only allow users to post every 30 minutes using swift? This delay time only works if the app is running, besides that it will not work or restart the time running every time the app launches. I need a way to have them wait for only 30 minutes. My code right now is:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background) .async {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1800)) {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "PostTimeLimit")
                }
            }
```

**Any tips or solutions would be very helpful. Thanks!**

Comment: You will have to store your lastPost timestamp. Every time you start the app/ enterForeground you will have to check the time difference. And then start a timer maybe for the time difference between current time and next post time. Stop this timer every time you go background/or terminate the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing whether or not the user is allowed to post, store their last post time and compare it to the current time.